# Is it possible to show pop up message in Excel Sheet?

Tags: excel-formula

I want to show pop up message to the user for the following scenario in Excel Sheet

In Excel Sheet, If values in A1 and A2 are not equal then the message should pop up with some entered text like "The value in A1 should be > A2") which guides user entering correct value.

Please let me know.
Thanks!

Comment: did my solution help you? if so, an accept would be nice.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do this, is using the inbuild data-validation of excel.

You find it on the data-tab on the ribbon-menu - looks like this:

[image]

You would need to set it up as "user defined" and specify your formula as `=A1>=A2`.

Further you can setup your "The value in A1 should be > A2" message to be displayed on cell-selection (input message) or as the pop-up messeage on entering a false number (error alert).

You will need to setup this data-validation for both A1 & A2, in order to have it displayed on any change of their relation.